# Check getter value by list of property name

Tags: java, spring

First of all, sorry if my question seems basic. I suppose I have one class with 100 properties and 100 getters and setters.

I'm aiming check not null value of some of these properties.

Exemple :

`If (object.getPropertyName()==null) System.out.println(" null value of Property Name")`

I wana do this for 50 properties. I could provide a list of properties to be checked in input. Is there anyway to capture getter name by property name and check them one by one without writing this 50 times ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understood your question, but you can use [Java Reflection API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection) for these kind of tasks.

Comment: Thanks. What i have seen from reflection it list all getters. In my case i want getter of specified properties ( list of properties)

Comment: You can do something like this. Put the names of the properties you'd like to access the getter of. Since getters have standards in naming like `getPropertyNameCamelCase`, you can create those getters' names. Then through reflection, those methods can be invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure, you can use this library here: [de.cronn.reflection-util](https://github.com/cronn-de/reflection-util).
It allows you to obtain descriptors from specific field names and then call their respective get/set methods. Like in the following source code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.setName("Test");
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptorByName(example, "name");
        System.out.println((String) PropertyUtils.read(example, descriptor)); // Will call getName
    }

}
public class Example {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```